# Help identify this tree, please

Tags: identification

Hoping someone could help identify this tree.  I'm ignorant on trees but this looks like it has this short main trunk and these long branches that shoot way up high.

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a shrub - this one's not been pruned as it should have been. It is Cotinus coggrygia, most likely the variety 'Royal Purple' though there are now other cultivars. It has a tendency to put out long stems at the top which only produce leaves near the top, leaving a gap of bare stem in between, as you can see from the photographs you posted. When it does that, those long stems should be pruned back to the main growth  to create a bushy plant. It is deciduous  and eventually will reach more than 12 feet tall; there is a green form often commonly known as Smoke Bush, because when it flowers, there are many more of them than on this variety and in a paler colour, so they give a foamy, smoky look to the plant. More info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotinus_coggygria